# Manually inputing validation set in GridSearchCV

Tags: scikit-learn

It seems like GridSearchCV has a "cv" parameter that defaults into splitting the inputted data set into training and validation sets. If I want to manually input a training and validation set, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: Well, that's not a cross validation anymore.

Comment: But you might still want to do model-selection using the convenience of GridSearchCV.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the ["PredefinedSplit"](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/cross_validation.html#predefined-fold-splits-validation-sets) class
available since 0.16.